# CSS3 Rotate Path within SVG Transform Origin / Firefox Issue

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-animations

I'm having an issue with Firefox (43.04) and Transform Origin with the rotation of a path within an SVG element.

Instead of using the origin of the targeted Rect, it's using the center origin of the entire SVG itself.  No problems in Webkit browsers.

Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/tj86Lz9g/

HTML

```
<a>
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 40">
      <rect class="square" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
      <rect class="rectangle" x="20" y="0" width="30" height="10"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

CSS

```
rect {
  fill:#FF0000;
}

rect.square {
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin:center center;
}

a:hover rect.square {
     transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Firefox is doing what the specification says to do. Webkit is not. Why then is it a Firefox problem?

Comment: @RobertLongson could you please elaborate on where the specification details that it's only in reference to the SVG itself? I'm having trouble finding it.  Furthermore, are you suggesting it is not possible to use Transform-Origin correctly on nested elements within SVG, and that Webkit itself has a bug?

Comment: Sure it's possible, it depends on what transform-orign means though which is defined here https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box

Comment: Having the same problem -- I have a path within an SVG and am trying to rotate it around its own center, but its instead rotating around the center of the svg its nested in...